# Working with webapp2, authentication, and Angular2

Tags: angular, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

I have a webapp2 app that I'm transitioning to use Angular2 as a front-end client. I have to use webapp2 auth as that is how user's sessions and information is stored. I'm having trouble getting the webapp2 app to write the session data cookie in my angular app.

Angular sample --
auth.service.ts:

```
// Simple POST request to GAE backend server
login() {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', JSON.stringify('some_user_info'), {headers: headers})
     .map(this.extractData)
 }
```

webapp2 Login handler:

```
class Login(BaseHandler):
   def post(self):
      self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      return self.auth.set_session({'user_id':'some_user_info'})
```

auth.set_session creates a UserToken but does not write a cookie in the browser client (Is this because Angular is the client, not the browser directly so webapp2 cannot save the securecookie?)

Ultimately I want to create an Angular2 client and a webapp2 REST backend that can handle authentication for the client.

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you trying to accomplish. You can store the token locally and use it as handshake authentication for any API call.

Comment: webapp2 already has an interface that handles user sessions via cookies and handles setting the cookies in the browser for you, so I was hoping that the webapp2 interface could be integrated into angular rather than create a separate token interface.

Comment: If you are using cookie-based auth, I believe 'http' should already handle the security cookie for you. You may use DevTools in browsers to check the details of HTTP request sent to your webapp2 back-end.

Comment: So I realized that the issue was because the RequestOptions in the Http request "withCredentials" was not set to true. It was my lack of understanding with Http requests in general. By setting withCredentials, webapp2 is able to receive and set cookie data.